# What are some ways to synchronize time between two wireless devices?

Tags: networking, time, synchronization

I am doing some initial planning for mobile app development and I will need the apps to have best time precision possible, down to millisecond if possible. What are some methods I can synchronize time between two devices and account for different network errors and lag - if I am to use a network method?

Comment: Can't you run ntp clients on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [PTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol#Implementations) is what you're looking for. It should provide sub-microsecond accuracy and seems to be available on different platform and devices. If you plan to use it on Android, probably you'll should start with porting [PTPd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTPd) on it.